# Autofocus on first input of Contact Form 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to insert the cursor into the first `input` of the form on page load (or `onclick` on the previous page).

Basically, I have a link on my homepage to 'enquire now' and I need it to click through to the contact page, scroll down to my anchor, and `focus()` on the first element of the form. I have tried `document.getElementById('____').focus();` but it only works when you're already on the page.

This is my button on the homepage:

```
<a href="/contact-us#contact"><button class="cta purple">Enquire Now</button></a>
```

And this is my input on the contact page:

```
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" id="first" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Name"></span>
```

Is this possible inline e.g. something like `document.getElementById('____').focus();` but for a new page? Or would a jQuery 'on page load' solution be the only option?

Comment: have you try this  $("#first").focus(); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. easiest way is to use HTML with [autofocus attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp)

```html
 <input type="text" name="your-name" autofocus>
```

2. or if you want to focus with javascript (jquery)

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#first').focus();
});
```

3. vanilla javascript

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('#first').focus();
});
```

Comment: Yes, I did find the `autofocus` solution amidst my googling, but the form is Contact Form 7 (the html is automatically created from the wordpress plugin).. is there a way of implementing it into that?

Comment: @coops any reason you don't want to use the JS provided?

Comment: @coops ah ok, then i would use the js solution. You can change WordPress plugins but on every plugin update you have a fair chance, that your changes are gone away. So in this case, i would recommend the javascript solution.

Comment: @d-h-e I see what you mean. I shall use the jquery solution as it works perfectly - thank you!